# How to add Strapi to a CPanel NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, server, cpanel, strapi

I can't understand how to install Strapi on CPanel? Obviously, I need an Application startup file (like app.js) but there is none on Strapi. If there is another method than creating an Application startup file, I have SSH access but I don't know how to do it... I'm new to NodeJS development so if you have a solution, it would be cool to be ample in explanation XD !

[The NodeJS configuration panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZFVH.png)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

From the [strapi docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/deployment.html#_2-launch-the-server), it says you can create a `server.js` file in order to startup with `node server.js` instead of `npm start`. Populate it with the following:

```js
const strapi = require('strapi');

strapi(/* {...} */).start();
```

i.e. point to this server.js file as the application startup file in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Following up @tsams' answer, these are the updated link for deployment requiring an application startup file like cpanel:

- for [Javascript only](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment.html)
- for [Typescript](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/typescript.html#start-strapi-programmatically)